# how to generate webfont from SVG icons

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, webpack, webfonts

Does anyone know how to generate webfont from SVG icons. I'm using webpack, angular2 and typescript in my project.

Can somebody give me idea how to achieve this? I'm not getting anything over the internet.
Please help me!!

[image]

[code here doesn't have too many information](https://github.com/DragonsInn/fontgen-loader)

I want to generate webfont for below svg icon.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this with **webfonts-generator** plugin

**Step1:**

1. Add "webfonts-generator": "^0.3.5" dependency in package.json
2. Create a folder icon under src and place all your svg files there
3. Add below code to your **webpack.common.js** file

**webpack.common.js**

```
const webfontsGenerator = require('webfonts-generator');
webfontsGenerator({
    files: [
         'src/icon/search.svg',
         'src/icon/error.svg',
         'src/icon/warning.svg'
      ],
    dest: 'custom-fonts/',
    fontName: 'custom-icons',
    html: true,
    templateOptions: {
      baseClass: 'custom',
      classPrefix: 'custom-'
    }
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Fail!', error);
    } else {
      console.log('Done!');
  }
});  

module.exports = {
loaders: [
  {
   test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
   loader : 'file-loader'
  }
]
}
```

4. Once you build, webfonts-generator plugin will create a folder named "custom-fonts" and generates css, eot, ttf, html pages etc..
5. By importing generated css file you can use the custom fonts

**Something.html**

```
<i class="custom custom-search"></i>
```

**O/P**
[image: custom search icon]

**Reference:**

[Generator of webfonts from svg icons](https://github.com/sunflowerdeath/webfonts-generator)

[Automated webfont generation from SVG icons.](https://github.com/DragonsInn/fontgen-loader)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom is a neat tool for generating a webfont from SVG input file(s).

When combined with Vagrant (or maybe also Docker, but so far I haven’t tried it with Docker), you can build a nice, fully-automated icon-generating workflow.